# Difference between scipy.spatial.KDTree and scipy.spatial.cKDTree

Tags: python, scipy, kdtree

What is the difference between these two algorithms?

Comment: also `cKDTree` will be more easily threaded because it may not suffer from the `GIL` (see `scipy.spatial` mailing list for more info). not sure as to which version of `cKDTree` was implemented without the `GIL`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

[cKDTree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree) is a subset of [KDTree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree), implemented in C++ wrapped in Cython, so therefore faster.

Each of them is

> a binary trie, each of whose nodes represents an axis-aligned hyperrectangle. Each node specifies an axis and splits the set of points based on whether their coordinate along that axis is greater than or less than a particular value.

but KDTree

> also supports all-neighbors queries, both with arrays of points and with other kd-trees. These do use a reasonably efficient algorithm, but the kd-tree is not necessarily the best data structure for this sort of calculation.

Comment: I am surprised this is not advertised more prominently in the KDTree docs and articles. For my simple (and presumably common) use case of finding neighbours in 3D for around 20,000 points, cKDTree was 40x faster.

Comment: @agf - cKDTree is actually implemented in C++. will you accept an edit ?

Comment: @gansub Sure, if you include a link to the source or something else that shows that it's C++.

Comment: @agf - https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/spatial/ckdtree.pyx distutils language c++

Comment: @gansub That appears to be Cython, not C++?

Comment: @agf - you will need to download scipy module and check the code  under scipy/spatial/src. There is a .cxx file there.

Comment: @gansub I tracked it down: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/master/scipy/spatial/ckdtree/src

Comment: What do "all-neighbors queries" look like?  I'm guessing it's kind of like a parallelized version asking for the nearest points to many points at once.  Can anyone confirm?

Comment: i'm with frank. i do not know what is "all neighbors queries". can you please explain what is "all neighbors queries"?

Answer (score 16):

In a use case (5D nearest neighbor look ups in a KDTree with approximately 100K points) cKDTree is around 12x faster than KDTree.

Comment: Another data point: Finding the two nearest neighbours among 1,640 points in 24-dimensions for around 50,000 test vectors: KDTree - 2m 32s / cKDTree - 360ms.

Comment: This answer would be 10x more helpful with speed tests to confirm, and/or the "all-neighbors queries" mentioned by @agf

Answer (score 4):

### Update 2022: cKDTree is deprecated

The current (v1.8) [SciPy](https://scipy.org/) documentation states that [scipy.spatial.cKDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) is now deprecated and was replaced by the functionally-identical [scipy.spatial.KDTree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html).

[Here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) is the note:

> cKDTree is functionally identical to KDTree. Prior to SciPy v1.6.0, cKDTree had better performance and slightly different functionality but now the two names exist only for backward-compatibility reasons. If compatibility with SciPy < 1.6 is not a concern, prefer KDTree.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, both have almost same APIs, and `cKDTree` is faster than `KDTree`.
So, In the near future, SciPy developers are planning to remove `KDTree`, and `cKDTree` will be renamed to `KDTree` in a backwards-compatible way.

Ref:
Detailed SciPy Roadmap — SciPy v1.6.0.dev Reference Guide
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/roadmap-detailed.html#spatial