# Python optomise nearest neighbour for large arrays

Tags: python, arrays, kdtree

I have an array of points in 4D space (my array is roughly 1,000,000 long).
For each value in my array I need to find the kth (where k = 81) nearest neighbours

I then do some further code based on that..

*[in brief, I'm effectively trying to extend the SSIM algorithm but for a picture sitting in 4D - I have a list of values with len(my_values)=1,000,000 = len(my_coords).
Although as an added complication my 'picture' is not made of points in a simple grid, but is more like a collection of 1,000,000 'point-stars' distributed psudo-randomly in 4D space - that for difference sets of 'my_values' have difference brightnesses, but always the same location...
That context may not be needed :) ].*

Roughly I need to do:

```
from scipy.spatial import KDTree 
mytree = KDTree(my_coords)
for i in range(len(my_coords)):
    dist, locs = mytree.query(my_coords[i], k=k)
    ....
    result.append(some_function(dist,locs,my_values_pic1[locs],my_values_pic2[locs]))
```

I tried querying mytree with the full 'my_coords' but this caused a memory problem. - also obviously that for loop takes forever.... so needs to be optomized.

I'm trying to change my loop to do chunks of about 300 points at a time and then stiching together the result -  I'm just wondering if I'm missing something obvious that could make this even faster?

Comment: I was shown the cKDTree [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931209/difference-between-scipy-spatial-kdtree-and-scipy-spatial-ckdtree/25875653#25875653) which appears to make things faster.



I will post some speed comparisons later.

Answer (score 0):

KNN only works efficiently for small datasets. In order to deal with larger ones efficiently, you'll have to perform data reduction by selecting prototype points that are capable of representing your classes accurately.

[Wikipedia has a good overview of the process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm#Data_reduction)

Comment: hmm,

I'll have a look at this.