# How to find the nearest x,y co-ordinate from a particular pixel using python

Tags: python, matplotlib, kdtree

My goal is to find the nearest x,y point co-ordinate for every pixel. Based on that i have to colour the  pixel points.

Here is what i have tried,
The  below code will draw the points.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

points = np.array([[0,40],[0,0],[5,30],[4,10],[10,25],[20,5],[30,35],[35,3],[50,0],[45,15],[40,22],[50,40]]) 
print (points)
x1, y1 = zip(*points)
plt.plot(x1,y1,'.')
plt.show()
```

[image: Here is the output of the above code]
Now to find the nearest point for each pixel.
I am found something like this where i have to give manually each pixel co-ordinates, to get the nearest point.

```
from scipy import spatial
import numpy as np
A = np.random.random((10,2))*100
print (A)
pt = np.array([[6, 30],[9,80]])
print (pt)
for each in pt:
    A[spatial.KDTree(A).query(each)[1]] # <-- the nearest point 
    distance,index = spatial.KDTree(A).query(each)
    print (distance) # <-- The distances to the nearest neighbors
    print (index) # <-- The locations of the neighbors
    print  (A[index])
```

The output will be like this,

```
[[1.76886192e+01 1.75054781e+01]
 [4.17533199e+01 9.94619127e+01]
 [5.30943347e+01 9.73358766e+01]
 [3.05607891e+00 8.14782701e+01]
 [5.88049334e+01 3.46475520e+01]
 [9.86076676e+01 8.98375851e+01]
 [9.54423012e+01 8.97209269e+01]
 [2.62715747e+01 3.81651805e-02]
 [6.59340306e+00 4.44893348e+01]
 [6.66997434e+01 3.62820929e+01]]
[[ 6 30]
 [ 9 80]]
14.50148095039858
8
[ 6.59340306 44.48933479]
6.124988197559344
3
[ 3.05607891 81.4782701 ]
```

Instead of giving each point manually i want to take each pixel from the image and i wanted to find the nearest blue point. This is my first question.

After that i want to classify those points into two categories,
Based on pixel and point i want to colour it, basically i want to do a cluster on it.
[image: Something like this am looking for]

This is not in proper form. But at the end i want it like this.
Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1):

- Use cKDTree instead of KDTree, which is faster (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15331547/9702190)).
- You can give the kdtree an array of points to query instead of looping over all of them.
- Constructing a kdtree is a costly operation compared to querying it, so construct it once and query many times.

Compare the following two code snippets, on my tests the second one run x800 times faster.

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

np.random.seed(0)
A = np.random.random((1000,2))*100
pt = np.random.randint(0,100,(100,2))

start1 = timer()
for each in pt:
    A[spatial.KDTree(A).query(each)[1]] 
    distance,index = spatial.KDTree(A).query(each)
end1 = timer()
print end1-start1

start2 = timer()
kdt = spatial.cKDTree(A)  # cKDTree + outside construction 
distance,index = kdt.query(pt)  
A[index] 
end2 = timer()
print end2-start2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use scikit-learn for this:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
labels = list(range(len(points)))
neigh.fit(points, labels) 
pred = neigh.predict(np.random.random((10,2))*50)
```

if you want the points itself and not their class labels you can do

```
points[pred]
```